# Problem with phpmd and Function libxml_disable_entity_loader()

Tags: php, laravel, docker, code-cleanup, phpmd

I'm trying to run this command: `docker run -it --rm -v ${pwd}:/project -w /project jakzal/phpqa phpmd app text cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode`

And it returns:

```
Deprecated: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated in phar:///tools/.phive/phars/phpmd-2.9.1.phar/vendor/symfony/config/Util/XmlUtils.php on line 54

Deprecated: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated in phar:///tools/.phive/phars/phpmd-2.9.1.phar/vendor/symfony/config/Util/XmlUtils.php on line 68

Deprecated:Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated in phar:///tools/.phive/phars/phpmd-2.9.1.phar/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 517
Deprecated: Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated in phar:///tools/.phive/phars/phpmd-2.9.1.phar/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 519
The given file "app" does not exist.
```

I've been looking for the solution for a few hours and I couldn't find anything. I already update phpmd in my project, but apparently the error comes from some other location that I couldn't find.

I'm developing a Laravel + docker project and trying to do some code validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the error

> The given file "app" does not exist.

It happens because you are not running this command inside the project's folder as suggested in the `${pwd}` syntax (Environment variable for actual working directory).

And the warnings regarding "libxml_disable_entity_loader", it's a bug related php8. It's openly discussed in the PHPMD GitHub issues, and you can skip this by just using the php7.4 version instead. Your command should look like the following:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${pwd}:/project -w /project jakzal/phpqa:php7.4 phpmd app text cleancode,codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode
```